# How to Set the View Using for Loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, view

I have to design screen like this.The Essential Category Contains 4 items,then Kitchen category Contains 8 items,then utility category contains 11 items.How to do this with reusability?

[image: Appliances Screen]

This is My Code which i tried:

```
- (void)buildAppliancesView
{
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        [self addAppliancesCategoriesLabel:i];
        [self addApplianceCategoryView:i];
        [self addIndividualAppliances:i];
    }
}

- (void)addAppliancesCategoriesLabel:(int)y
{
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,(_appliancesHeaderLabel.frame.origin.y+_appliancesHeaderLabel.frame.size.height)+y*150+10, 0, 0)];
    NSLog(@"y=>%f",label.frame.origin.y);

    label.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[APPLIANCESCATEGORIESLABEL_ARRAY objectAtIndex:y]];
    [label sizeToFit];
    [_scrollView addSubview:label];
}

- (void)addApplianceCategoryView:(int)y
{
    applianceCategoryView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, label.frame.origin.y+label.frame.size.height+5, self.view.frame.size.width-10, 70)];
    [applianceCategoryView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [_scrollView addSubview:applianceCategoryView];
}

- (void)addIndividualAppliances:(int)y
{
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        UIView *applianceView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5+((self.view.frame.size.width/4)+5)*y, _appliancesHeaderLabel.frame.origin.y+_appliancesHeaderLabel.frame.size.height+label.frame.size.height+10, 50, 50)];
        NSLog(@"xVAlue==>>%f",applianceView.frame.origin.x);
        [applianceView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(changecolor)];
        [applianceView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

        [applianceCategoryView addSubview:applianceView];
    }    
}
```

Comment: Before commenting anything need to know working of that screen, are  all items are scrollable if yes then in which direction? whole item will scroll or only particular? means if user scroll kitchen item only those item will scroll?

Comment: @VijayPalwe no. all items have to scroll from top to bottom.My problem is, how to Run forloop 4 times,8 times and 11 times.Also how to Increase the Essential size prefectly for $ items and Kitchen View for 8 items.

Comment: Ok use scrollview, take x and y globally, dont create separate uiview, Create one function in which write a code to create uilable
-(void)createLableForPosition:(int)xpos andYposition:(int)yPosition

 and another function write a for loop into it 
-(void)createItems:(int)numberOfItem {
for()
}

Comment: so now you can use it for each category and their items and use total height as content size of that scrollview

Comment: @VijayPalwe i didn't get ur answer.Am a newb to iOS.I didnt have enough time.Please Provide me a solution code.

Comment: -(void)addItem:(int)iten{
    
    for(int i=0;i<iten;i++){
        
        height = height + 40;
      
        UIButton *intrestBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        intrestBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [intrestBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 80, 80)];
        [scrlView addSubview:intrestBtn];
        y = y +95;
        scrlView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(768,y+80 );
    }
}

Comment: -(void)createTitle
{
    UILabel *intrestTitleBg=[[UILabel alloc] init];
    [intrestTitleBg setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 80, 20)];

    [intrestTitleBg setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [scrlView addSubview:intrestTitleBg];
    scrlView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(768,y+80 );
    y= y + 30;

}
i created this two functions and call it like this [self createTitle];
    [self addItem:3];
    [self createTitle];
    [self addItem:5];

Comment: first function is for creating your title and then second function for adding items under it

Comment: IN second function you need to set number of item you want and this is all sorry code is not written properly but it works let me know does it help or not by voting up to answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103077/discussion-between-raghunath-and-vijay-palwe).

Comment: bro i forgot to tell you using current code your item will look in one row you need to make changes for  x also, let me know if its not able to do to you

Comment: Why are you trying to replicate a `UICollectionView`? Just create a data model where `Essentials` and `Kitchen` are sections with items as rows. Then use the `UICollectionViewController` to construct your scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this - sample code for creating views in loop.

```
int xPosition = 0;
int yPosition = 0;//set your y origin
int height = 150; // sample value
int width = (NumberOfItems.count)/4;
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfItems.count; i++) {  
   UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initFrame:CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, width, height)];
   [self.scrollView addSubview:view];
   xPosition += width;
   if(xPosition == 3*width){
      xPosition=0;
      yPosition = yPosition + height; // set as per your requirement
   }
}
```

Using UIScrollview for this will be better.

OR

Here is the sample code for your scenario.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

//    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapDetected:)];
//    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired=1;


    UIScrollView *ScrollVc = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    ScrollVc.delegate = self;
    ScrollVc.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    [ScrollVc setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:ScrollVc];
    ScrollVc.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
//    [ScrollVc addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];


    NSArray *essentialsArr = @[@"1",@"2",@"3"];
    NSArray *KitchenArr = @[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6"];
    NSArray *abcArr = @[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4"];
    NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:essentialsArr,KitchenArr,abcArr, nil];

    int yPosition = 0;//set your y origin
    int yPositionOfMain = 0;//set your y origin

    for (int k = 0; k < arr.count; k++) {

        int xPosition = 0;
        int height = 100; // sample value
        int width = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)/4;

        UIView *mainview = [[UIView alloc] init];
        mainview.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        [ScrollVc addSubview:mainview];

        for (int i = 0; i < [[arr objectAtIndex:k] count]; i++) {
            if (i==0) {
                xPosition=0;
                yPosition= 0;
            }
            UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPosition + 10, yPosition, width-20, height)];
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            [mainview addSubview:view];
            xPosition += width;
            if(xPosition == 4*width && i!=[[arr objectAtIndex:k] count]-1){
                xPosition=0;
                yPosition = yPosition + height + 10; // set as per your requirement
            }
        }
        mainview.frame = CGRectMake(0, yPositionOfMain, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, yPosition + height + 10);
        yPositionOfMain = yPositionOfMain + mainview.frame.size.height + 20;
    }

    if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height==736)// iPhone 6 Plus         66 Navigation bar
    {
        [ScrollVc setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,950)];
    }
    else if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height==667)// iphone 6       44 Navigation bar
    {
        [ScrollVc setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,900)];
    }
    else if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height==568)//  iphone 5, 5C, 5S   44 Navigation bar
    {
        [ScrollVc setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,800)];
    }
    else                                                    //  iphone 4, 4S   44 Navigation ba
    {
        [ScrollVc setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,750)];
    }
}
```

Please change the necessary values as per your requirements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My problem is, how to Run forloop 4 times,8 times and 11 times.Also how to Increase the Essential size prefectly for $ items and Kitchen View for 8 items.

Comment: @sathish what i have to give in that number of items.Bcoz it changes for Different categories...

Comment: NumnerOfItems is the array of items in essentials/kitchen or you can directly mention number that how many views you want in specific essential/kitchen.

Comment: @sathish not getting ur Code....Pls explain it clearly.If kitchen as 8 items,how to increase the height of that kitchen View and add the 5th item in a second row....

Comment: So thanks.But How can i set Yvalue for label name.If i write like this its not working,  `UILabel *label =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2,mainView.frame.origin.y+mainView.frame.size.height+2,0,0)];`

Comment: Labels for Kitchen & Credential Strings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103180/discussion-between-satish-a-and-raghunath).